# Subversion, possible to have a several folders to always point to a common folder?

Tags: svn, tags, branch

We tag weekly baselines and have several development branches. The tag/branch contains several folders. One of the folders is a folder that should be common for all branches. I would like to remove it completely from all of our branches, so that only the version used in Trunk would be used. However, the folder is still needed in all branches. If I remove it completely from other branches than trunk, then developers would still need to always make sure they have also checked out the folder from Trunk so the build can be compiled.

To avoid hassle, instead of removing the folder from all other branches than Trunk, is it possible to include the folder in all branches but it always to point to the folder version in Trunk? So it would look like this, where folder C is the folder in question:

```
TRUNK:
    - folder A
    - folder B
    - folder C

BRANCH1:
    - folder A'
    - folder B'
    - folder C -> points to TRUNK branch

BRANCH2:
    - folder A''
    - folder B''
    - folder C -> points to TRUNK branch
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the `svn:externals` property. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html. The basic idea is you create a definition on a directory, that will pull in a different directory in the repository to a certain location whenever someone performs a checkout. Probably you would need to re-arrange a little, so that "trunk" also uses this property to pull in folder C rather than having folder C directly under the "trunk" directory.

Note that since you are using branched development, it is probably a good idea to point to explicit revisions of folder C in your svn:externals definition as recommended at the link given. Doing so will prevent changes to Folder C on Branch1 from affecting other branches. You are also free to branch Folder C if you want.